# Fetch corresponding States of Countries table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have two tables `Country` and `CountryStates` with the following fields

```
Country
- CountryId
- CountryName

CountryStates
- StateId
- StateName
- CountryId
```

There are some Countries without any states added in the database.
Now we have to fetch only those countries where states are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query to retrieve only countries that have a state:

```
SELECT *
FROM    Country AS C
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 
                FROM    CountryStates CS
                WHERE   CS.CountryId = C.CountryId
            )
```

Comment: No need to use `TOP 1` with `EXISTS`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) like this

```
SELECT CountryID,CountryName 
FROM Country C
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM CountryStates S 
    WHERE S.CountryID = C.CountryID
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a [JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208854(v=office.12).aspx) (also known as [INNER JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208854(v=office.12).aspx)) on CountryStates, using the CountryId.

This will leave you with only the details of Countries which have a state added for them.

```
SELECT *
FROM Country
INNER JOIN CountryStates ON Country.CountryId = CountryStates.CountryId
```

Answer (score 1):

**Same Result can be obtained by using sample INNER JOIN..**

SELECT CountryID,CountryName
 
FROM Country C
INNER JOIN CountryStates S
 
ON C.CountryID = S.CountryID